# How to decipher no parking signs? (UK)

Tags: uk, automobiles, road-signs

[image: No parking sign]

Please excuse the poor resolution of the image.

My understanding is that these signs normally show the restrictions and then the applied times.

So does this sign mean that a lorry or coach can NOT park between 6:30pm and midnight and midnight to 8am ? That is a coach or lorry CAN park there between 8am and 6:30pm.

Does that imply that cars can park there at any time?

Comment: Please do not just pictures on SE sites; [edit] your question and quote the text that's in it - especially with this bad quality.

Comment: A description would be less useful than an image in this case. As it is about a sign so it is integral to the question.

Comment: The sign prohibits waiting, according to the [Traffic Signs Manual](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/traffic-signs-manual)

Comment: Read my comment again. I did not say text **instead** of a picture. We can only just barely make out that the picture shows a "no parking" and not a "no stopping" sign. On SE sites we want text next to the pictures, so that it is searchable. Half of the points [mentioned here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) apply to your question.

Comment: @JanDoggen If the asker knew what the sign meant, then they wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: What is the source of the image? Where is that sign?

Comment: An example is here: https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@51.5367269,-0.1303859,3a,75y,304.41h,83.49t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sQRK_p5B4vQgS22Ok5PcVQA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656 this does not seem to be in a controlled zone because there is no sign saying controlled zone before (Coming from Camley St)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Page 53 of the UK publication "[Know Your Traffic Signs - Official Edition](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/519129/know-your-traffic-signs.pdf)" (published by the UK Department for Transport) has an example showing just the 5T lorry and describes it as follows:

> Repeater sign indicating the times when waiting by goods vehicles over
>   the maximum gross weight shown is prohibited. There are equivalent signs for buses with the bus symbol, and signs that apply to both goods vehicles and buses.

So in your example, between 6:30pm and midnight and midnight to 8am, there is no waiting for goods vehicles with a maximum gross weight over 5T and no waiting for coaches.

Comment: But cars can wait/park there at any time?

Comment: If that's the only sign, then yes.